# Page speed metric for Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, firebase-performance

I have seen the Page speed for the web https://pagespeed.web.dev/
I want to calculate the amount of time taken between the user lands on the screen until the app completes processing and rendering the content.
Have tried some analytics tools such as Firebase performance, Posthog, Mixpanel, Google Analytics, and Instabug. But no tool provided the analytics which I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclosure: engineer at PostHog)

That's not built into PostHog but you can format graphs/insights as durations. So if you start a timer and then capture a custom event into PostHog you can analyse those values.

Here's an example of where we do that on our website with our web library.
https://github.com/PostHog/posthog/blob/master/frontend/src/lib/utils/eventUsageLogic.ts#L657

```
const properties: Record<string, any> = {
    //<snip/>
    lastRefreshed: lastRefreshed?.toISOString(),
    refreshAge: lastRefreshed ? now().diff(lastRefreshed, 'seconds') : undefined,
}
```

Comment: Hey Paul, I was looking for a already build tool, I have the custom solution but the accuracy isn't always 100%, thats why I am looking a tool which can calculate this time.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to calculate the amount of time taken between the user landing on the screen until the app completes processing and rendering the content.

If you are interested in measuring/improving the app’s launch time, then most likely you have to follow the guide that exists at the following URL:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

If you perform some Firebase operations then you should consider using [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon), which is a service that can help you gain insight into the performance characteristics of your app. So this means that you'll be able to measure the amount of time taken between when the user lands on the screen until all network operations are complete and the corresponding content is rendered on the screen.

Google Analytics isn't useful here, because it only provides a service that tracks and reports website traffic.

Comment: Hey, Jagdish. Can I help you with other information? Did my answer help you?

Comment: Hey Alex, Firebase performance doesn't provide the time at which all the data on a particular screen is shown. And launch time is different from what I am looking for. 
For example: I want to calculate the time between I launch instagram and posts, stories are visible on the screen.

Comment: In that case, you should start a counter when you launch the app, and stop it when all network operations are complete, right? However, Firebase Performance Monitoring can help you calculate how fast the operations actually are.